# Unique Visitors and Pageviews discrepancy between two accounts for a single domain

Tags: google-analytics

We have created two accounts for a single domain. Both these accounts reside in a separate  code. There's a huge variation in unique visitors and pageviews (attached) between these two accounts in the standard dashboard. Any idea where we are doing wrong?. FYI: We set up event tracking for only one account where we are seeing more unique visitors and pageviews. Does event tracking inflate UVs and PVs? Since this is a standard reporting not a custom reporting, I guess it must be something to do with page tagging. 
Appreciate any help.! [Variation in UVs and PVs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaMrV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Google Analytics is not 100% accurate**. I know, it's surprising.

Here's one reference for that:
http://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/2188027/little-google-analytics-matter

Basically, through ignoring some data and "sampling" the rest, Analytics is more like an Exit Poll than a fully traceable Ballot.

To get such a difference, if we assume there is no random element at play in GA, there must be a slight difference in the data the two accounts collect. At the very least, one must be fired before the other. If a small number of users closed their browsers during the page load there would be a difference which would then multiply up with the sampling.

It is indeed also possible that the event tracking will affect the data held. This is speculation but it would make sense that tracked events are less likely to be ignored. It would follow from that that you could massage "raw" Analytics by adding the right Events, and take advantage of the fact that Google Analytics is not 100% accurate. However, massaging two accounts to have the same numbers is nigh on impossible.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the insight. We would have ignored it if it was a slight difference but this is huge as you can see the attached img. The account where we are seeing more UVs/PVs comes after the other account, so firing might not be the issue here. Only culprit left is events. but we are not to sure.